# Stitching images in Android

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm trying to stitch images one below other and render the final image in `WebView` of Android.

This is my code for the same:

```
File f1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mydownload/"+"1.jpg");
File f2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mydownload/"+"2.jpg");
File f3 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mydownload/"+"3.jpg");
try {
    joinImages(f1, f2, f3);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

private void joinImages(File first, File second , File third) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("in join images------------------------------");
    Bitmap bmp1, bmp2, bmp3;
    bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(first.getPath());
    bmp2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(second.getPath());
    bmp3 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(third.getPath());
    /*if (bmp1 == null || bmp2 == null)
        return bmp1;*/
    int height = bmp1.getHeight()+bmp2.getHeight()+bmp3.getHeight();
    System.out.println("height-========================== "+height);
    System.out.println("widht================ "+bmp1.getWidth());
   /* if (height < bmp2.getHeight())
        height = bmp2.getHeight();*/

    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, bmp1.getHeight(), 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp3,bmp1.getHeight()+bmp2.getHeight() , 0, null);

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mydownload/"+"final.jpg");
    bmOverlay.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
    out.close();

    //return bmOverlay;
}
```

But the image which is being save is containing only one image instead of three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your drawBitmap calls offsetting the width instead of the height?

Assuming you want the bitmaps one on top of the other, should you be doing:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, 0, 0, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, bmp1.getHeight(), null);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp3,0, bmp1.getHeight()+bmp2.getHeight() , null);
```

instead of

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, 0, 0, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, bmp1.getHeight(), 0, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp3,bmp1.getHeight()+bmp2.getHeight() , 0, null);
```